# How to access an already opened Excel file in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, office-interop, excel-interop

I have an excel workbook opened via double-clicking it in windows explorer but cannot access it in code

```
Excel.Application xlApp = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
Excel.Workbooks xlBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
```

xlBooks.Count equals 0, why isn't it referencing my opened workbook?

**EDIT**

Here are the various scenarios and what is happening:

Scenario 1: If the file is not already open

- Code opens workbook, I am happy.

Scenario 2: If the file is initially opened from code and I close and reopen the app

- Code references file just fine `xlBooks.Count` equals 1, I am happy.

*Scenario 3*: If the file is initially opened not from code, and via double-clicking it in explorer

- Code opens another instance of the file `xlBooks.Count` equals 0, **I am in a rage!**

Here is the entire code as it stands right now

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class ExcelService : IExcelService
{
    const string _filePath = @"C:\Somewhere";
    const string _fileName = @"TestFile.xlsb";
    string _fileNameAndPath = Path.Combine(_filePath, _fileName);

    Application xlApp;
    Workbooks xlBooks;
    Workbook xlBook;
    Worksheet xlSheet;

    public ExcelService()
    {
        try
        {
            xlApp = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
            xlBooks = xlApp.Workbooks;

            var numBooks = xlBooks.Count;
            Log.Info("Number of workbooks: {0}".FormatWith(numBooks));
            if (numBooks > 0)
            {
                xlBook = xlBooks[1];
                Log.Info("Using already opened workbook");
            }
            else
            {
                xlBook = xlBooks.Open(_fileNameAndPath);
                Log.Info("Opening workbook: {0}".FormatWith(_fileNameAndPath));
            }

            xlSheet = (Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets[1];

            // test reading a named range
            string value = xlSheet.Range["TEST"].Value.ToString();
            Log.Info(@"TEST: {0}".FormatWith(value));

            xlApp.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e.Message);
        }
    }

    ~ExcelService()
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        try
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlSheet);
        }
        catch { }

        try
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlBook);
        }
        catch { }

        try
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlBooks);
        }
        catch { }

        try
        {
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Comment: You sure you don't have more than one instance of Excel?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682678/accessing-an-open-excel-workbook-in-c

Comment: Show us the line of code where you attempt to open the "already opened" spreadsheet.

Comment: Dupe of his own question... wow...

Comment: yea i'm pretty sure, i'm watching task manager for multiple instances and there is only the one that I currently have opened.. i'm also doing `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);` in the destructor

Comment: @Armbrat @Tipx I'm trying to ask more narrowing questions... I'm not getting answers... sorry

Comment: So, in task manager, you only have one excel.exe open?  Correct?

Comment: I think i have other stuff going on... I moved all this code to a console app and it worked and then it didn't again... i'm going to inspect more tomorrow... thanks

Comment: Ok, I'm curious to hear your findings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all your workbooks are opened in the same Excel instance (you can check this by checking if you can switch from one to the other using Alt-tab). You can simply refer to the other using `Workbooks("[FileName]")`. So, for example :

```
Dim wb as Workbook //for C#, type Excel.Workbook wb = null;
Set wb = Workbooks("MyDuperWorkbook.xlsx") //for C#, type wb = Excel.Workbooks["MyDuperWorkbook.xlsx"];
wb.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = "Wahou!"
```

Comment: Is this for Office 2013 and later? I am using Office 2010 and Excel.Workbooks doesn't accept a "string" input argument.

Comment: The answer was given nearly 5 years ago, so it's most likely for Excel 2010, but I can't remember.

Comment: @Tipx any idea how this could be done using Apache POI (in Java).

Comment: @Devendra Sadly, I have no ideas, sorry.

Answer (score 12):

I know this thread is a little old, but I found another way of doing this. When you create a new `Excel.Application`object you have to create the WorkBooks object. When you access an already opened Excel file, the `WorkBooks` object is already created, so you just need to add a new WorkBook to the existing one. @Tipx 's solution works great if you have access to the WorkBook name, but in my case the current WorkBook name is always random. Here's the solution I came up with to get around this:

```
Excel.Application excelApp = null;
Excel.Workbooks wkbks = null;
Excel.Workbook wkbk = null;

bool wasFoundRunning = false;

Excel.Application tApp = null;
//Checks to see if excel is opened
try
{
    tApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
    wasFoundRunning = true;
}
catch (Exception)//Excel not open
{
    wasFoundRunning = false;
}
finally
{
    if (true == wasFoundRunning)
    {
        excelApp = tApp;
        wkbk = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);                    
    }
    else
    {
        excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        wkbks = excelApp.Workbooks;
        wkbk = wkbks.Add(Type.Missing);
    }
    //Release the temp if in use
    if (null != tApp) { Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(tApp); }
    tApp = null;
}
//Initialize the sheets in the new workbook
```

Might not be the best solution but it worked for my needs. Hope this helps someone. :)

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: @Nathan any idea how this could be done using Apache POI (in Java).

Comment: @Devendra Sorry I do not know; I didn't even know that existed, I will have to look into it when I have the time.