# Assign excel workbook to local variable when the excel is already open

Tags: c#, excel

What I am trying to do is create a Windows App that opens some excel workbooks, does some calculations and the saves and closes the excel files.

I cannot seem to be able to focus on one of them without having to open them, like:

```
oBook1 = oBooks.Open("C:\\Reports\Excel1.xlsx");
oBook2 = oBooks.Open("C:\\Reports\Excel2.xlsx");
```

What I need to be able to do is to assign Excel1.xlsx to oBook1 and Excel2.xlsx to oBook2 when the excel files are already open.

Is there a away to do this? I have tried several ways found online but nothing works.

Until now I managed to do the assignment only by opening them one by one like the example above.

Thank you.
Danut

Edit 1:

I am trying to get a list of excel workbooks open and then to select the one i need from there. My code is:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcelApp;

             oExcelApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

             foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook WB in oExcelApp.Workbooks)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(WB.FullName);
             }

             oExcelApp = null;
```

When I try to assign oExcellApp I get the folowing error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2012/05/14/the-definitive-locked-file-post.aspx

Comment: anyone can help with this?

Comment: I tried what is posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686886/how-to-access-an-already-opened-excel-file-in-c but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the workbooks collection and test to see if the one you want is already there; if not, open it.  Here's the VBA version of this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oWb As Workbook
    Set oWb = GetWorkbook("name_of_file.xlsx")
    If oWb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "File is not open; you'll have to open it yourself."
    Else
        MsgBox "File is already open and you have a reference to it in oWb."
    End If
End Sub

Function GetWorkbook(sName) As Workbook
    Dim oWb As Workbook
    For Each oWb In Application.Workbooks
        'Debug.Print oWb.Name
        'Debug.Print oWb.FullName ' You could also check the full path
        If sName = oWb.Name Then
            Set GetWorkbook = oWb
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but i am having a hard time moving this to C#.

Comment: Can't help you with that, I'm afraid.

Comment: No problem, thank you. I will wait for another answer.

Comment: Why is the answer in VB? this is a C# question.

Comment: Automating Office apps is a two-part problem:  you have to learn the app's object model and then figure out how to use whatever language you like to use the object model.  I provided a simple object model example in the language I'm familiar with.  If it helps you, you're free to adapt it to C#.  If you're unable to do that, you're free to ignore my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
You are missing a cast as your error implies. The GetActiveObject function gets an "object" type, not an Excel.Application type. However it can be cast as an Excel.Application type. Try this:

```
oExcelApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
```

**Long answer:**
This is a very old question, but I have recently struggled with this problem and found a solution in C#, so here is my full solution.

First, I setup the using and global variable needed:

```
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    Application excelApp;
```

Second, I have a function which Initializes the Excel application object as follows:

```
    public void InitExcelApp()
    {
       try
       {
          excelApp = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
       }
       catch(COMException ex)
       {
          excelApp = new Application
          {
             Visible = true;
          };
       }
    }
```

Third, I created a function to get the open workbook object. This assumes you know the path of the open workbook. In my project, this is a safe assumption.

```
// This path MUST be windows style. I use Path.GetFullPath(mypath) before passing the path as a string.
private Workbook getOpenWorkbook(string path) 
{
   foreach (Workbook xlWorkbook in excelApp.Workbooks)
   {
      if (xlWorkbook.FullName == path)
      {
         return xlWorkbook;
      }
   }

   return null;
}
```

Lastly, I just call this function whenever I want to set a workbook object to an open workbook (with known path).

```
Workbook myWorkbookName = getOpenWorkbook(path);
```