# connectrion my C# code to external Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I use to Open Excel files from my C# Interop application.
However, I cannot pick up (or get connected to) Excel file, when it is already "in air" - open manualy.

```
app = new Excel.Application();
foreach(var w in app.Workbooks)
{
    if(w.name == "MyFile") found = true;    //never ever found 
}
```

Could you please advice How To get connected to MyFile.xlsx, not just Open it?

Comment: Are you asking how to open a workbook? - `var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(@"c:\path\myfile.xlsx");`

Comment: No Alex! app.Workbooks.Open I use many years. My question about openning (get connecting?) to the Excel file already open manualy by User.

Comment: `Marshal.GetActiveObject()` E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686886/how-to-access-an-already-opened-excel-file-in-c

Comment: Thanks Alex for point me this thread, it is definitely what I need!