# Writing to the activecell in excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have the following code which write a value to the activecell in the excel. It works fine 50% of the time but not the last 50% it does not.
Why??

```
void ValueToExcel(string value)
{

   Excel.Application oXL=null;
   Excel.Workbook oWB=null;
   Excel.Worksheet oSheet=null;
   Excel.Range rng =null;
   try
   {
      oXL = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
      oXL.Visible = true;
      oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oXL.ActiveWorkbook;
      oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;                
      rng = oSheet.Application.ActiveCell;                
      rng.Value = value;
      rng.Application.ActiveCell.Offset[1, 0].Select();
   }
   catch (Exception EX)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(EX.Message);
   }
}
```

I tried to change the code but it still not works. It seems that the value is written to some other Excel application.

```
void ValueToExcel(string value)
{
   //Gets Excel and gets Activeworkbook and worksheet
   Excel.Application oXL=null;
   Excel.Workbook oWB=null;
   Excel.Worksheet oSheet=null;
   Excel.Range rng =null;
   try
   {
      while (oXL==null)
         oXL = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

      oXL.Visible = true;

      while (oWB == null)
         oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oXL.ActiveWorkbook;

      while (oSheet == null)
         oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;

      while (rng == null)                
         rng = oSheet.Application.ActiveCell;

      while(rng.Value=="")
         rng.Value = value;

      MessageBox.Show(value);

      Console.Beep();

      rng.Application.ActiveCell.Offset[1, 0].Select();
   }
   catch (Exception EX)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(EX.Message);
   }
}
```

somebody have some help?

Comment: *`It seems that the value is written to some other Excel application.`* which in my opinion means you are getting the wrong handle of Excel. If you have two workbooks open at the same time you might not be getting the correct workbook. Check the `oXL.Name` or title of the window you are handling.

Comment: Thank your for your input !!!
To test the code I did following:
1) restart
2) start 1 Excel application up
3) run code
Sometimes a new Excel App is started when I run the code.
Dont understand why?
I'll try you suggestion

Comment: Wondering if the reson is that it's a bagground thead which calls the code?

Comment: oXL.Name only gives "excel.application"

Comment: When I was testing code to manipulate Excel, a debugging problem I had was that aborting the program didn't close Excel, so there were multiple old instances floating around.  So, check the Program Manager and kill any rogue Excel processes, first.

Comment: Solved. I changed thread to main thread and the code seems reliable

Comment: Not quite solved anyhow. On another computer the code keeps starting new instances of Excel up. It seems that it dont recognize the active one

Comment: By the way thanks  you very much John c for your input. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Seems that when I open a excel file from explorer it works.
If I open it from excel it does not.

Comment: Ah. I see. The `Interop` code, as far as I know, isn't very good at _actual_ interoperability. The intent is to use Excel "headless," as if it was just a library. I was going to say you might be out of luck, but I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682678/accessing-an-open-excel-workbook-in-c-sharp), which might help (I don't have a Windows system handy).

Comment: Thank you John. Seems that there is no good solution. 
I changed to code. Let C# open an instance of Excel and link to this instance.