# Why ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Count is showing zero even when I have an Excel workbook open

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, office-addins

`ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Count` is showing count = 0 even when I have a document open.

`ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Count` shows count = 1 when the document opened is not in protected view. But when the opened document is **PROTECTED VIEW** the `ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Count` shows 0.

**Why the workbook count is 0 in case of protected view excel?**

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Paste your code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Because](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.protectedviewwindow.workbook):

> A workbook displayed in a Protected View window is not a member of the Workbooks collection.

If you need to get a handle on a protected workbook:

```
using (var protectedWorkbook = ExcelApplication.ProtectedViewWindows(1).Workbook)
{
    // do stuff 
}
```

A robust solution would account for the possible fault condition of multiple `ProtectedViewWindows`. The above code assumes there is one and only one.

Comment: This will result in COM object leak since you can't free the ProtectedViewWindow COM instance that you acquired

Comment: Feel free to revise, I'm on mobile.

Comment: Thanks David, Link helped. Also observed that in PROTECTED VIEW if I try to set Application.Interactive property to false. It throws generic error `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` I looked into the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.interactive there's nothing explicitly mentioned that not allowed to set the interactive property when document is in PROTECTED VIEW

Comment: Is this presumption correct the it's not allowed to set `Interactive` property for protected view document?

Comment: Seems reasonable maybe but I'm not sure.